# Get contents of a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, function

I was trying to make a function in JavaScript that could set the `onClick` property of an HTML button.

So, say I have this as my function:

```
function myFunc(action){
    document.getElementById('mybtn').setAttribute("onClick", action);
}
```

That would set `mybtn`'s attribute `onClick` to the contents of the variable `action` (which should be a function).


So, if I ran the function like this:

```
myFunc(function(){
    alert("Hello, World!");
});
```

Then the variable `action` would be set to

```
function (){
    alert("Hello, World!");
}
```

If I ran `myFunc` as shown, it would successfully add the contents of `action` to the button's `onClick` attribute. The only problem is, if I click the button after `myFunc` has been run, I just get an error. It says:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (


I think that's because in the `onClick` attribute, you can't have a new function defined.

How can I get only what's inside the function in the variable `action`?

Comment: Instead of updating the onClick property of the element, just bind the function `action()` as a listener via Javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add an event listener instead of altering the attribute for onclick like this:

```js
function myFunc(action) {
  document.getElementById('mybtn').addEventListener('click', action);
}

myFunc(function() {
  alert('foo');
});
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">Foo</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Attribute values can only be strings. Your function is stringified to something like

```
'function(){ alert("Hello, World!"); }'
```

And then the event handler parses it as a function body. That means it will be treated as a function declaration, but function declarations require a name. Therefore, yes, there is an unexpected `(`: there should be a name before it. Firefox provides a more meaningful error

```
SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
```

```js
function() {
  alert("Hello, World!");
}
```

If you really want to use event handler content attributes, you should pass a string containing only the body of the function:

```
myFunc('alert("Hello, World!")');
```

```js
function myFunc(action){
  document.getElementById('mybtn').setAttribute("onclick", action);
}
myFunc('alert("Hello, World!")');
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">Click me</button>
```

But I strongly discourage event handler content attributes. Instead, use event handler IDL attributes:

```
function myFunc(action) {
  document.getElementById('mybtn').onclick = action;
}
```

```js
function myFunc(action) {
  document.getElementById('mybtn').onclick = action;
}
myFunc(function (){
  alert("Hello, World!");
});
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">Click me</button>
```

Or even better, event listeners

```
function myFunc(action) {
  document.getElementById('mybtn').addEventListener('click', action);
}
```

```js
function myFunc(action) {
  document.getElementById('mybtn').addEventListener('click', action);
}
myFunc(function (){
  alert("Hello, World!");
});
```

```html
<button id="mybtn">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`html` `onclick` event attribute expects a string, not a function. You can defined function to be called then pass string referencing function to `myFunc`

```html
<div id="mybtn">click</div>
<script>
  function myFunc(action) {
    document.getElementById("mybtn").setAttribute("onclick", action);
  }
  
  function clickHandler() {
    alert("Hello, World!");
  }

  myFunc("clickHandler()");
</script>
```